# Flask-SocketIO not receiving message

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

SocketIO version 1.3.6

Python 3.6

I am using Flask-SocketIO in my python app to send and receive message. I am able to send message (I see the output in terminal) but the client is not receiving the message (no output in console).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000/');
  socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log("connected")
  });
  socket.on('message', function(msg) {
    console.log('Received message');
  });
  $('#submitmsg').on('click', function() {
    socket.send($('#usermsg').val());
    $('#usermsg').val('');
  });
});
```

Chat window HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <p class="welcome">Welcome<b></b></p>
        <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="#">Exit</a></p>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="chatbox"></div>

    <form name="message" action="">
        <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
        <input name="submitmsg" type="submit" id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
    </form>
</div>
```

EDIT: Adding server code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('message')
def handleMessage(msg):
    print('Message: ' + msg)
    send(msg, broadcast=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

If the received message works, I should see `'Received message'` in the browser console but I do not see it. What am I missing? Any suggestion?

Comment: You did not include the server-side code in your question.

Comment: @Miguel added server side code now.

Comment: Did you see the output for `console.log("connected")`?

Comment: @GreyLi yes I see that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `<input name="submitmsg" type="submit" id="submitmsg" value="Send"/>` to submit the form, it will generate a `POST` request, then your page will be reload, that's why your JS function `socket.on()` in the page will not be called.

Apparently, with Flask-SocketIO, you needn't to use the POST request. So just change it to `<button name="submitmsg" id="submitmsg">Send</button>` and remove `<form>` tag, i.e.:

```
<div id="wrapper" display = 'none'>
    ...
    <div id="chatbox"></div>

    <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63"/>
    <button name="submitmsg" id="submitmsg">Send</button>
</div>
```